# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(SObject) from the type List&lt;OpportunityTeamMember&gt;

Tags: apex

I am trying to insert Opportunity team member dynamically based on few conditions, it is throwing below error. (Note: for testing purpose I hard coded the values)

*Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(SObject) from the type List<OpportunityTeamMember>*

**Code:**

```
public static sObject insertOppTeam(String objName,String User_Id, String Opportunity_Id, String TeamMember_Role, String Opportunity_AccessLevel){
    sObject sObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objName).newSObject();
    sObj.put('UserId', User_Id) ;
    sObj.put('OpportunityId', Opportunity_Id) ;
    sObj.put('TeamMemberRole', TeamMember_Role) ;
    sObj.put('OpportunityAccessLevel', Opportunity_AccessLevel) ;
    return sObj ;
}
public static Map<String, MR_Digitization_Settings__mdt> teamRoles = GlobalUtility.fetchOpptyTeamRoles(); 
List<OpportunityTeamMember> opteam = new List<OpportunityTeamMember>();
String test1 = 'ABC';
String test2 = 'XYZ';
if(test1 == 'ABC'){
   
    sObject ot = insertOppTeam('OpportunityTeamMember','0057400000KAAY','0062H00001kyQAH','trole','Edit');
    opteam.add(ot);
}
if(test2 == 'XYZ'){
  
     sObject ot =insertOppTeam('OpportunityTeamMember','005740000mlZKAAY','0062H00001kyQAH','trole2','Edit');
    opteam.add(ot);
}
     if (!opteam.isEmpty()) {
                Database.insert(opteam, false);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sObject` is the superclass of every sObject type, including `OpportunityTeamMember`. When you have an instance of a superclass (`sObject`), you cannot use it interchangeably where a subclass (`OpportunityTeamMember`) is called for, because that instance might in fact be storing some other subclass (`Account`, say).

In this case, your `opteam.add()` call requires an instance of `OpportunityTeamMember`, because `opteam` is a `List<OpportunityTeamMember>`. That list cannot store a generic `sObject`, which might in fact be an instance of another subclass.

If you know based on your logic that that superclass variable *does in fact* contain an instance of the required subclass, you can cast it:

```
opteam.add((OpportunityTeamMember)ot);
```

At runtime, you'll get an exception if `ot` actually contains a type other than `OpportunityTeamMember`.

However, that's not the best way to fix this code. You've written this code using dynamic methods you do not need, which make the code significantly less clear (and also a lot slower). There's no need to dynamically access the schema to instantiate an object here, or to populate its fields; you know the type and the field names at compile time!

If you wish to retain a method that instantiates `OpportunityTeamMember` records, replace your `insertOppTeam()` method with something like this:

```
public static OpportunityTeamMember createOpportunityTeamMember(Id User_Id, Id Opportunity_Id, String TeamMember_Role, String Opportunity_AccessLevel){
    return new OpportunityTeamMember(
        UserId=User_Id,
        OpportunityId=Opportunity_Id,
        TeamMemberRole=TeamMember_Role,
        OpportunityAccessLevel=Opportunity_AccessLevel
    );
}
```

This method adds very little to your code; you could simply replace each call to it with an explicit `new OpportunityTeamMember()`.